# PostGIS - ST_SetValues is slow

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have large data in my C++ program (up to 3000x3000). I have connection to PSQL with PostGIS. Now I need to store my raster data (greyscale images) in DB raster. I am using [ST_SetValues](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SetValues.html) for this and convert image data to string query in this format

```
ARRAY[[9, 9], [9, 9] .... ]::double precision[][]
```

The rest of query is just

```
UPDATE data SET vals = ST_SetValues(vals, 1, 1, 1,  ARRAY[...]) WHERE id = 1;
```

Problem is, it takes too long to update data (up to 1 minute), Is there a faster way?

Comment: Is the one minute the runtime of your program or the runtime of the pure query in the db? The connection takes long when you have a loop running with the data as the db goes through the whole table for each iteration checking for constraints for example. You can see this by having a look at your database connections while your program runs.

Comment: @Matte I am measuring only this: `PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, query);`,  `if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) { ... }`,  `PQclear(res);`

Comment: How big is your raster, the bigger it is the longer since it will have to make a copy for each update.